# If I have N distinct points, how many different ways can I construct a set of distinct points?

Tags: math, computer-science, combinatorics

Lets say that I have 2 groups of distinct points. I'm trying to find all the possible different ways to travel between these points. In one group we have P1,P2 and in the other group P3,P4. Any point can be a starting point and can only end in the opposing group. I want to find a way to formalize how to find all combinations of these points. Each group can have an N distinct number of points, but I chose for each group to have 2 points. These are all the possible set of points from these two groups:

- Set 1: P1->P2->P3->P4
- Set 2: P1->P2->P4->P3
- Set 3: P2->P1->P3->P4
- Set 4: P2->P1->P4->P3
- Set 5: P3->P4->P2->P1
- Set 6: P3->P4->P1->P2
- Set 7: P4->P3->P2->P1
- Set 8: P4->P3->P1->P2

The "->" denotes a path traveled. Therefore I have 8 distinct paths traveled. How do I formalize this though? I've tried thinking of exponents, and factorials... I'm a bit stuck right now.

Comment: It's 2(N!)^2, but I had to infer your real constraints from your example. For instance, you forbid P1->P3->P2->P4.

Comment: Yes, I forbid P1->P3->P2->P4 because each Point in a group needs to be traveled to before moving to the other group.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Comment: Even better than Mathematics would be cstheory.stackexchange.com

Comment: cstheory.stackexchange is for research-level questions, which this is not.  It should be migrated to either cs.stackexchange or a mathematics board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bipartite graph, with n vertices on each side.

Choose your starting point on the left: n options.

Choose your destination on the left: n-1 options.

Choose your next destination on the left: n-2 options remaining.

etc...

Then choose a destination on the right: n options.

Then choose your next destination on the right: n-1 options remaining.

etc...

Then multiply that out and also take into consideration the fact that you can start on the right-hand side instead of the left.

(Also... this question perhaps will be migrated to a math board.)

Comment: Each point in the left group must be traveled to before moving to a destination point on the right. All points will essentially be traveled to.

Comment: You said, "Any point can be a starting point and can only end in the opposing group."  I took that to mean each edge has to start in one group and end in the other, but it looks like you just mean the whole path has to start in one and end in the other.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Answer edited to correct for the misunderstanding.  Answer is as mentioned in the comments: 2(n!)^2

Comment: What if both groups had a different number of points?

Comment: Using the same reasoning I describe here, it is 2(n!)(m!).

Comment: Ah, I see now. I understand. Thanks a lot!